# Redim without Dim?

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm using Access 2010 under Win7.  I've discovered I can dimension my arrays at run-time by simply invoking `ReDim arrayName(x)` without first declaring the array as `Dim arrayName()`.

```
Sub FooBar()
   ReDim myArray(2)
   myArray(0) = "This is the first string in myArray."
   myArray(1) = "This is the second string in myArray."
   myArray(2) = "And this is the last string in myArray."
   MsgBox myArray(0) & vbCrLf & myArray(1) & vbCrLf & myArray(2)
End Sub
```

Is there any reason I should NOT use this shortcut?

Cheers!

Comment: Shortcut? `Redim myArray(0)` is 2 characters longer than `Dim myArray(0)`.

Comment: But you can't dynamically dimension an array at run time.  So, if you don't know the array size prior to compiling, I'm told that you're "supposed" to do this: `Dim myArray()` and then `ReDim myArray(x)` where 'x' is the integer/long value of the array size.

Comment: That is correct. You hadn't mentioned the dynamic dimension part in your initial question. Rgds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's interesting.  [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264224.aspx) confirms what you're seeing: Here's a quote:

> "You can use the ReDim statement to declare an array implicitly within
>   a procedure. Be careful not to misspell the name of the array when you
>   use the ReDim statement. Even if the Option Explicit statement is
>   included in the module, a second array will be created."

This page explains that `Redim` creates a new array and that the existing array is copied into it (assuming there is one):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

As to your question, should you do it, I'd say no, because it's confusing, and does open your code to errors that Option Explicit won't catch.

Reasonably enough, `Redim Preserve` doesn't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Doug, for digging up the documentation.  I don't want to confuse anyone, including myself, and so I **WAS** going to go ahead and add the explicit `Dim` statement.  However, I could `Dim myArray` and then `ReDim myArary(x)`, and `Option Explicit` in this case won't protect me from a "_Subscript out of range_" run-time error.  So, I think I'm actually safer from undefined variables if I skip the `Dim` and just declare and and dimension the array once with the `ReDim`.  However, you did the legwork and offered your considered opinion, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking the same thing as what you're saying here and I agree that in this case Option Explicit won't protect you.  I run M-Z Tools - http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx - and use its Review Source Code tool, which tells me if i have unused variables.  So that might catch the misspelled Redim, assuming I never Redimmedd with the correct spelling.  I salute (and +1) you for bringing up this interesting quirk.