# Dynamically Size the Upper Bound of a VBA User Defined Type

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-types

I'm working with a two-dimensional array that stores a location and date under each iteration. I dynamically set the upper bound of that dimension using a counter variable ("i"), i.e.:

```
ReDim arrLocDt(1 To i, 0 To 1)
```

When debugging in the Watch window, I always found it cumbersome that I couldn't name the individual items, for example, instead of

```
arrLocDt(1,0) and arrLocDt(1,1)
```

I would like to see:

```
arrLocDt(1,Location), arrLocDt(1,Date), arrLocDt(2,Location), arrLocDt(2,Date), etc.
```

Recently, I learned about `User-Define Types` which would allow for just such labeling of items. Thus I tried the following:

**1. Defined a new UDT**

```
Public Type MyType

     strLocation As String
     strDate As String

End Type
```

**2. Tried the following definition with a dynamic sizing of the upper bound**

```
Dim test(1 to i) As MyType
```

*The above failed because I got the error `Constant Expression Required`.*

Please advise how I can dynamically size the upper bound of an UDT, and if that's not possible, an alternative that would still allow me to label my items.

Comment: You might want to look at Classes also.  You can do more with a Class than with a Type.  And you can use a collection (or dictionary) object to store a bunch of your class objects; by using the Add method you don't need to know how big your array will be.

Comment: Why don't you explore using Dictionary instead? [Take a look at this](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) very useful information. I haven't had experience in UDT so I'm proposing an alternative which I think is very suitable to what you want to accomplish. If you want to explore and somehow get lost, I or somebody from here will assist you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as:

```
Dim arrLocDt() As MyType
ReDim arrLocDt(1 To x) As MyType
```

(The first `Dim` is actually not required.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907050/redim-without-dim) post for details.)

The reason you're running into problems is that you initialize (`Dim`) an array of any type with a variable size. E.g., this is illegal too:

```
Dim myStringArray(x) As String
```

...it's not just a UDT thing. Dynamically sizing or resizing an array can only be done at run-time with a `ReDim`.

That said, you could do this:

```
Dim arrLocDt(1 to 10) As MyType
```

And then later, when you need a different size, do this:

```
ReDim arrLocDt(1 To x) As MyType
```

...but you cannot simply start out with this:

```
    Dim arrLocDt(1 to x) As MyType
```

So, again, if you don't know what the initial size is going to be, just declare the array without any bounds... `Dim arrLocDt() As MyType` and then `ReDim` as soon as you know the size and you need to use it.

Also, cool tip, if you need to resize a second time, and you want to keep what is in there, use the `Preserve` Key Word, like this:

```
ReDim Preserve arrLocDt(1 to y) As MyType 'resizing, but keeping my stuff
```