# Declaring a dynamic array not working as expected

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, dynamic-arrays

```vb
RsProxyList.Open objDBCommand,,1,1
dim recCount:recCount = RsProxyList.RecordCount
Dim output(recCount,2)
```

I get an error because recCount is of wrong type. I have tried to convert it to `Int` but that does not work either. The following works fine:

```vb
RsProxyList.Open objDBCommand,,1,1
dim recCount:recCount = RsProxyList.RecordCount
Dim output(3,2)
```

How do I convert `recCount` to get this array declaration to work?

Comment: _dim recCount:recCount_ ???? Certainly not in VB.NET

Comment: The you should try `Dim recCount = CInt(RsProxyList.RecordCount)` and be sure to not retrieve more thant 32767 records

Comment: @Steve You can't declare and assign in Classic ASP like that, plus the OP has already said they *"tried to convert it to **int** but that does not work either"*.

Comment: `.RecordCount` is already an `integer` the issue is you can't dynamically set the dimensions of a fixed array, it all comes down to how the array is declared.

Comment: What is the array for?, you do realise if you want to populate an array from a `ADODB.Recordset` you can just use the `.GetRows()` method which returns a two dimensional array of columns and rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first declare your Array as dynamic then use `ReDim` to set the first dimension dynamically, like this;

```vb
Dim output() 'Declare a "Dynamic Array"
ReDim output(recCount, 2) 'Set dynamic first dimension.
```

By specifying the dimensions like this;

```vb
Dim output(10, 2) 'Declare a "Fixed Array"
```

you tell VBScript to build a fixed array which does not accept variables as dimension declarations.

---

### `Dim output()` versus `Dim output`

There seems to be some argument as to using

```vb
Dim output()
```

versus

```vb
Dim output
```

> [@Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237785/bond) in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059518/declaring-a-dynamic-array-not-working-as-expected/26059851#comment40838674_26059851) came up with the most convincing one in my opinion for using `Dim output()`.
>
> Because VBScript stores all variables as `Variant` data type declaring an `Array` using `Dim output` is just like declaring any other variable, whereas `Dim output()` creates an `Array` (0 sized array but an array nonetheless), this means there is one significant difference as far as the VBScript Runtime is concerned, `Dim output()` is an `Array`.
>
> What does this matter?, well it matters because functions like `IsArray()` will still detect the variable as an `Array` where as "arrays" declared using `Dim output` will return `False`.

---

**Useful Links**

- [@DougGlancy's answer to Redim without Dim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907481/692942) (vba but still relevant).
- [VBScript Reference - Dim Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [VBScript Reference - VBScript Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx) (specifically Array Variables sub heading).