# Is there any reason to use "redim" when creating a dynamic array instead of "dim" in excel VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a two-dimensional dynamic array in Excel VBA. Most of the code examples I can find are like the following:

```
Dim companyArray() As Variant
Dim height, width As Integer
width = 2
height = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))
ReDim companyArray(height, width)
```

Is there a reason I wouldn't want to declare the array after I've gotten a value for the `height` variable? Would I not want to avoid using ReDim if it's possible?

Comment: Dim and ReDim aren't interchangeable, they do different things.

Comment: You "dimmed" `companyArray` already so you have to use `redim`. The alternative is not to `Dim` the variable in the upper part of your code and then immediately use `Dim` where you are currently using `ReDim`. You can `Dim` a variable only once and from there on you have to use `Redim`. (At least that's the theory. In actually its this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907050/redim-without-dim)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dim companyArray(1 to 5)` is static sizing: needs that the bounds are constants known at the time you write the code.

`Redim companyArray(1 to x)` is dynamic sizing, required when the bounds are computed while the program is running.

When any of the bounds (on any dimension) is not known at coding time, `Redim` is the only option.

---

**A word of caution**

`Redim` does not need that the variable be dimmed before, you can just declare and redim a dynamic array. **However**, There is some risk in doing so. Consider this

```
' Module
Dim X as variant ' some module-level (or global) variable
''''''''''''''''''
' Some code
'''''''''''''''''
Sub foo()
   Redim X(1 to 3) as long ' <-- Will redim the global X
   ....
End Sub
```

If the intent of the programmer when writing `foo` was to declare a *local variable* and `Redim it` in one shot, then this will fail, because the `Redim` statement will operate on the global X because it is within scope.

The bottom line is that `Redim` declares and redims the variable, **but** if a variable with the same name exists in its scope, it will redim that variable instead of creating a new variable. For this reason, even though it is not strictly necessary, it is safer to use `Dim` before `Redim`, by rules of good practice.

```
Sub foo()
   Dim X() as Long
   Redim X(1 to 3) as long ' <-- Will now refer to the local variable X
   ....
End Sub
```

Comment: "coding time", aka "compile-time" ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug, Visual very Basic for Applications. :)